# Git Server With A Working Copy

Tags: php, git, web, repository

I am looking to set up a remote repository on a server that I can push changes on a website to. However, I also want to server to have a working directory, or at least be able have the development version of the website running with the latest changes to the repository.

Do I need to create a local branch on the server to checkout the repository files every time I push changes? Or is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I highly recommend you use [Capistrano](http://capistranorb.com). It is a tool that makes it very easy to deploy a website. It would handle creating a local git repository on your server and checking out the latest version when you run the deploy script. It makes it very easy to deploy to multiple environments (development, staging, production) and it also makes it easy to rollback to previous versions if you discover a bug. All of this is done from your local computer, you would not have to log in to the server after having everything setup.

Comment: I have installed it and the latest version of rubygems via: `$ \curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby` and install capistrano with `$ gem install capistrano`, but it says capistrano is not installed when I run: `$ capify .` Any advice?

Comment: You should run `bundle exec cap install` instead of `capify`. I recommend following the instructions on [github-capistrano](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano)